# Multiple ID jQuery Selector returns different than when a single ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have some dropdown menus which I have originally setup to figure out which dropdown has been selected then loads the elements, no problems.

Now I've added a new set of dropdowns and my existing function now applies to this one as well because it was very broad

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {...}
```

Now i have these dropdowns on 4 different tabs in a modal and I only want the last tab to function differently than the other three, so I want to make a function which works for the original 3 tabs and one for the 4th type of tab.

First three tabs IDS

```
#racksTab
#condenserTab
#glycolTab
```

Fourth tab (different)
    #alertTab

So my question is why do i get different results when my selector uses multiple IDs compared to just 1

```
$(document).on('click', '#racksTab,#condenserTab,#glycolTab .dropdown-menu li a', function () {...}
```

This function gives me 
[image: multiple ids selector]

But if i make the selector only use one id, it gets the child node i want

```
$(document).on('click', '#racksTab .dropdown-menu li a', function () {...}
```

[image: Single ID selector]

Comment: Why not just `$('#Rack1')`? And if there are others use their IDs as well.

Comment: The `.dropdown-menu li a` doesn't apply to all the three IDs, it only applies to the last one, I think you need to use this selector instead: `#racksTab .dropdown-menu li a, #condenserTab .dropdown-menu li a, #glycolTab .dropdown-menu li a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with this selector :

> #racksTab,#condenserTab,#glycolTab .dropdown-menu li a

You are targeting three elements:

1. Element with Id `racksTab`
2. Element with Id `condenserTab`
3. `a` element inside `li` child of `.dropdown-menu` child of Id element `glycolTab`

I guess you want all elements like the third one, so your selector must be:

> #racksTab .dropdown-menu li a, #condenserTab .dropdown-menu li a, #glycolTab .dropdown-menu li a

---

<sub>**Note:** Maybe you don't need those selectors at all, I think you can improve your code with a more suitable selector as @j08691 points on the comments, but all will be based on the real markup, if you add it we can help U improve the code.</sub>

Comment: Nicely explained +1

Comment: Ooh ok this makes sense, for some reason i thought the `.dropdown-menu li a` would be applied to all three id selectors rather than just the last one.

Comment: @EricG always remember that selectors on Jquery works pretty much the same way like on CSS

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you were aiming for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#racksTab .dropdown-menu li a, #condenserTab .dropdown-menu li a, #glycolTab .dropdown-menu li a'
```